# Android dashboard image size

Tags: android-layout, android-imageview, android

Hello I am implementing a Dashboard to my application, where i want to overlay 4 images (one to top_right of parent, other to top_left, bottom_right and bottom_left). The reason why i want to overlay is because the images will fit together like a "puzzle".My question is, how can i set these images sizes to be a quarter of the screen,(having in mind multiple screens).

Thanks

Comment: you can take relative layout in that you can place control as above requirement

Answer (score 0):

You can take the help of RelativeLayot.it has control like

```
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```